# Appending an array to a Json Value in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, json, jsoncpp

I know that if I have some integer 'a' and 'b' that I can append them to a Value in Json:

```
Value root;
Value v = root["int"];
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
v.append(a);
v.append(b);
```

Resulting Json file:

```
"int": 
  [
    1,
    2
  ]
```

But is there also a way to append entire arrays? Perhaps something like this:

```
Value root;
Value v = root["arrays"];
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int b[3] = {4,5,6};
v.append(a);
v.append(b);
```

I'm trying to have my resulting Json file look like:

```
"arrays": 
  [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]
  ]
```

But instead, Json only appends the pointer address value, which reads as "true":

```
"arrays": 
  [
    true,
    true
  ]
```

Comment: you're looking for an `.extend()` method

Comment: whats the result for the second code?

Comment: Yeah, an extend() is exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't find one within jsoncpp (https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp). I don't think copy() helps, because I still can't get that array data into the Json file properly.

Comment: Rithik: the last box is what I get.

Comment: hyde: range-for is close, but it just dumps in all the values of the two arrays without structure, like this: "arrays": [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit way is to use range-for with a temp `Value`.

```cpp
Value root;
Value v = root["arrays"];
int a[3] = {1,2,3};
int b[3] = {4,5,6};

Value tmp;
for(auto i : a) { tmp.append(i); }
v.append(tmp);

tmp = Value{}; // reset
for(auto i : b) { tmp.append(i); }
v.append(tmp)
```

---

A possible helper template function to wrap it nicely:

```cpp
template<typename RANGE>
Value rangeToValue(RANGE src) {
    Value result;
    for (const auto &value : src) {
        result.append(value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then this should work:

`v.append(rangeToValue(a));`
`v.append(rangeToValue(b));`

Comment: Heck yes! You're my favourite person of the day, hyde. Thanks!